# Adding text scale to jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How to add the scales like poor, excellent, very good in the jQuery UI slider plugin

```
|-------|--------|-------|
poor excellent  good   verygood
```

Comment: thanks for editing my question do you know the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Filament Group's [jQuery UI selectToUISlider plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/)

Comment: whether that poor,good,excellecent  text scales values can we bring it from database if poosible give some idea?instead of giving satic values....

Comment: @Karthik You can use any of jQuery's ajax functions to load the data from the database and create the `select` element using JavaScript before applying the plugin to it.

Comment: can you provide me some sample pls.....jQuery's ajax functions to load the data from the database pls it will be easy to me

Comment: @Karthik There are plenty of example on each of the functions in the jQuery API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/