# Jquery UI Slider: progressive scale divisions and grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, scale

I need to do a slider like on the picture below:

[image: slider]

I would be nice to use standart Jquery UI Slider, but it don't support scale divisions by default and it is tricky to do irregular scale (not 1|2|3|4|5 but 1|2|5|10|20).

There is alternative slider plugin (http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/), but it don't support a possibility to change slider position by clicking on scale.

Are there some simple solutions to my task?

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498441/adding-text-scale-to-jquery-ui-slider

Answer (score 2):

Storing the desired values in an array and "picking" one by the value of the slider seems the easiest solution to me, since you anyways have to supply the labels yourself:

```
var steps = [0, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 300];

$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: steps.length,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").text(steps[ui.value]);
    }
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/mwh2u/